# Java - Get All Permutations, Substrings and Permutations of every Substring of a String

Tags: java, string

Firstly, I'll start off by saying English is not my first language so I apologize for any poor explanations.

I want to know how to get every single substring of a String with so many different orders. Before you tell me this question has been asked before, I want to say that almost every code implementation of this task I see does not include duplicates. But Say I had a string "enviroment" and I wanted every single substring including "ment", "met", "ten", "net","note", "more" e.t.c e.t.c how would I acheive this??

This is the function I wrote.

```
     public static ArrayList<String> getAllSubstringsOfAString(String inputString)
     {
     ArrayList<String> allSubstrings = new ArrayList<String>();
     String sub;
     for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
     {
        for (int j = 1; j <= inputString.length() - i; j++)
        {
            sub = inputString.substring(i , i + j);
            allSubstrings.add(sub);
        }
      }
      return allSubstrings;
     }
```

When I run this function

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> allSubStrings = getAllSubstringsOfAString("environment");
    for (String allSubString : allSubStrings) {
        System.out.println(allSubString);
    }
```

it prints this out

```
    e
    en
    env
    envi
    envir
    enviro
    environ
    environm
    environme
    environmen
    environment
    n
    nv
    nvi
    nvir
    nviro
    nviron
    nvironm
    nvironme
    nvironmen
    nvironment
    v
    vi
    vir
    viro
    viron
    vironm
    vironme
    vironmen
    vironment
    i
    ir
    iro
    iron
    ironm
    ironme
    ironmen
    ironment
    r
    ro
    ron
    ronm
    ronme
    ronmen
    ronment
    o
    on
    onm
    onme
    onmen
    onment
    n
    nm
    nme
    nmen
    nment
    m
    me
    men
    ment
    e
    en
    ent
    n
    nt
    t
```

Which is only a small part of what I want. I want the function to be able to get substrings in every order. For example, If I wanted it to include Strings like "net", "ten", "never" e.t.c, as they are all substrings of the word "environment".  What changes do I have to make on my function to attain this?

Also, as I am a Java beginner, I would like to know If my code is well written and what changes I can make to my code to make it perform better and look better, and to follow common Java coding conventions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: well, you can write an algorithm to write all the substrings and then you can reverse all of them and add into your list.

Comment: but "ten" is not exactly a substring, although you can get this word just reusing the same letters that are present your string

Comment: @Leo "ten" is not a subtring??? What is it called then? And how would I add it to my arrayList?

Comment: it's a permutation of one of the substrings

Comment: @Kaylo17 it's called "string" right because it's a sequence of letters. So we can say "ent" is a substring of "environment", but "ten" is not. If you also want to get values such as "ten" given a string like "environment", what you're looking for (it seems to me) are the permutations of the letters that are present in the word "environment"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating all permutations of a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen no this problem is a bit more complex since he wants all permutations, all substrings and their permutations. Similar but woulnd't call it a duplicate. P.S. hey from Tamachi station.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Retracted my close vote.

Comment: Leo and Mateusz thank you for your help. So I'm looking for the permutations of the string and the substrings. Looking at the problem this way might make it easier to solve. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) generate all substrings (you got that part already)

2) for each substring generate all it's permutations - you can do it either recursively or iteratively using a bitvector (it's been shown here on SO how to do it, a quick google search will also give you some hints)

3) add all to the final list, this will get you what you already have, reversed version of what you have and all other permutations

For example with "abc" you will get:

> - a (1 char, 1 permutation)
> - ab (substring)
>
>   - ba (substring permutation)
> - abc (substring)
>
>   - bca (substring permutation)
>   - bac (substring permutation)
>   - acb (substring permutation)
>   - cab (substring permutation)
>   - cba (substring permutation)

Be aware it might take some time to compute, when a string has N it has N! permutations and you will be calling it for each substring so N times which will yield O(N*N!) time complexity.

As @PM77-1 pointed out this might do a lot of unnecessary work if our string has duplicated substrings like abcabc. In that case before each new iteration you can check if the given substring is already in the set (yes, you change the resulting list to a set which has O(1) lookups) and skip it if it's already there.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll write out the function and post it. I'm not worried about time complexity right and efficiency since this is mostly for learning purpose

Comment: @Kaylo17 - Do not forget to eliminate all duplicates, possibly by converting your list to set and back.

Comment: @PM77-1 fair point, my algorithm is very naive in that regard btu since he doesn't mind the time complexity I guess it's not a problem.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk okay, So after a bit of work, I came up with this program. http://pastebin.com/hzknuhac . If you have time, could you tell me how to improve it or make it more efficient. I also realized that for words longer than 9 letters, I get an Out of memory exception

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of help from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189698/string-permutations-in-java-non-recursive), I threw this together.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = perms("codes");
    list.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}

public static List<String> perms(String string) {

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    char[] values = string.toCharArray();
    for (int width = 1; width <= values.length; width++) { // for every length
        int stack[] = new int[width];
        for (int i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) { // start from a specific point without duplicates
            stack[i] = stack.length - i - 1;
        }
        int position = 0;
        while (position < width) {

            position = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (position < width) { // build the string
                sb.append(values[stack[position]]);
                position++;
            }
            result.add(sb.toString());
            position = 0;
            while (position < width) {
                if (stack[position] < values.length - 1) {
                    stack[position]++;
                    if (containsDuplicate(stack) == false)
                        break;
                    else
                        position = 0;
                } else {
                    stack[position] = 0;
                    position++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static boolean containsDuplicate(int[] stack) {
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < stack.length; j++) {
            if (stack[i] == stack[j] && i != j) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't re-use letter from the word unless the word contains the letter twice.
In which case there would be doubles.
It doesn't use recursion so stack overflow won't be a problem.

Comment: It works a lot better than the one I created. Thanks a lot. It still has an out of memory exception when I put in more than 7 characters though. I'll find a way to fix that though. Thanks again.

Comment: The problem will be holding onto such a large list of string. You can pass in a consumer and handle each string as it is generated. An interesting task would be to break this task up over multiple threads.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting way to do it. I'll try and work on it over the next few hours and see what i can come up with

Answer (score 0):

The Program below returns all possible sub set and their respective permutations.

- For example for value **abcd@1234** it will return **986410** possible values from it.
- **[Note]**: it will work differently with permutations containing same characters. 
   Example for value **aaaa@1234** it will return **6850** possible values from it.

```java
public class PermutationWithSub {
    public void subStrings(String string){
        List<List<Character>> listList = new ArrayList<>();
        listList.add(new ArrayList<>());
        ArrayList<String> subStringArraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> bruteList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (char c:string.toCharArray()){
            int size = listList.size();
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
                List<Character> temp = new ArrayList<>(listList.get(i));
                temp.add(c);
                listList.add(temp);
            }
        }
        for (List<Character> characterList : listList) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (Character character : characterList) {
                stringBuilder.append(character);
            }
            subStringArraylist.add(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
        for (String str:subStringArraylist){
            List<List<Character>> listListChar = permute(str);
            for (List<Character> listChar:listListChar){
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (Character character:listChar){
                    stringBuilder.append(character);
                }
                bruteList.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        }
        listList.clear();
        subStringArraylist.clear();
        for (String str:bruteList){
                System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    public List<List<Character>> permute(String string){
        List<List<Character>> powerSet = new ArrayList<>();
        generateSet(powerSet,new ArrayList<>(),string.toCharArray());
        return powerSet;
    }

    private void generateSet(List<List<Character>> powerSet, List<Character> temp, char[] chars) {
        if (temp.size()==chars.length){
            powerSet.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
        }else {
            for (char aChar : chars) {
                if (temp.contains(aChar))
                    continue;
                temp.add(aChar);
                generateSet(powerSet, temp, chars);
                temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyBruteForceTool myBruteForceTool = new MyBruteForceTool();
        myBruteForceTool.subStrings("abcd@1234");
    }
}
```