# How to convert this function from recursive to tail-recursive?

Tags: c#, recursion, permutation

I have this method:

```
static List<string> permutation(List<string> lst)
{
    switch (lst.Count)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            return lst;
        default:
            List<string> l = new List<string>();


            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
            {
                string m = lst[i];
                List<string> remLst = lst.Except(new List<string> { m }).ToList();

                List<string> tmp = permutation(remLst);
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < tmp.Count; i2++)
                {
                    l.Add(m + tmp[i2]);
                }
            }
            return l;
    }
}
```

which gives all permutations of the list `lst`.

The idea is to one by one extract all elements, place them at first position and recur for remaining list. Python equivalent [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-python/).

How to convert it from recursive to tail-recursive?

Comment: Tail recursion just involves reassigning `lst` and looping back to the beginning of the function (obviously only possible if there are no more inner loop iterations remaining)

Comment: @Wyck So is there any way to make it iterative? I heard every recursive has an iterative equivalent.

Comment: If you have a stack, yes.  Without a stack, no.  Tail-recursion alone won't do it.

Comment: Without a stack, you can do permutations via the _next lexicographical permutation_ algorithm.  [Description](https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm).  [C# Implementation](https://www.nayuki.io/res/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm/nextperm.cs)

Comment: Not a dupe because it's Java, but you can probably use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915026/permutations-of-a-string-using-iteration).

Comment: Aside: `List<string> tmp = new List<string>(permutation(remLst));` - you don't need a copy here, you can just do `List<string> tmp = permutation(remLst);`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this recursive `Fibonacci` program -

```cs
using System;

class MainClass {

  public static int Fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
      return n;
    else
      return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
  }

  static void Main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      Console.WriteLine(Fibonacci(i));
    }
  }
}
```

For any given function, only the last operation can be in [tail position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). So tail recursion is impossible for our program because there are *two* calls to `Fibonacci` right? No -

```cs
class MainClass {

  public static int Fibonacci(int n) {
    return FibCont(n, a => a); // <- call helper
  }

  private static T FibCont<T>(int n, Func<int, T> k) {
    if (n < 2)
      return k(n);
    else
      return
        FibCont(n - 1, a =>       // <- tail call
          FibCont(n - 2, b =>     // <- tail call
            k(a + b)              // <- tail call
          )
        );
  }

  static void Main() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

[Continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) (demonstrated above) easily allows us to convert *any* recursive program to an iterative one; and without having to dramatically change the program's shape. `Permutation` can be similarly transformed using a CPS technique -

```
static List<string> Permutation(List<string> lst) {
  return PermCont(lst, a => a) // <- call helper
}

static T PermCont<T>(List<string> lst, Func<List<string>, T> k) {
  switch (lst.Count) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      return k(lst); // <- send answer to k
    default:
      string m = lst[0]; // <- first item
      List<string> remLst = lst.Except(new List<string> { m }).ToList();

      // remLst represents the smaller problem
      // solve the smaller problem and get the result
      return PermCont(remLst, result => {
        // result contains the permutations of remLst
        // construct the answer using remLst and m
        // answer = ... 
        return k(answer); // <- send answer to k
      })
  }
}
```