# Algorithm for bruteforcing a known randomized key at runtime

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

let's say I have this string literal (used as a key), for example:

'h' 'i' 'i' 'a' 'm' 'a' 'c' 'a' 't'

And it was passed into the application like this (randomized):

't' 'i' 'h' 'a' 'i' 'a' 'm' 'c' 'a'

What is an algorithm that would unsort this (in a for loop), which will then attempt to decrypt the data, which will then check a value at a known offset, if false then start the loop over.

- Note this will be used with a 256 bit AES key at runtime.

Question : How long would it take on average with the algorithm - taking into account it is with a AES 256 key? (Time isn't an issue here, just curious)

Thanks all.

IMPORTANT EDIT - STD functions or any CRT cannot be used, as my application is incompatible.

Comment: I don't understand `with a AES 256 key`. What algorithm are you using? AES-256 takes a binary key, not a string key.

Comment: I generated a key which was used for encryption, I then randomized it completely (swapping random characters), I then therefore must work out how to de-randomize it, back to the original.

Comment: Why would you randomize it? I hope you are not designing a system that transmits secret keys over an insecure channel. An existing system such as TLS is probably much better suited for what you need.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'derandomization'. If you could 'derandomize' it was not 'random' to begin with - it was predictable.

Comment: Yeah well, you know what I mean? Get it back to it's original state

Comment: You need to store some information that allows you to restore the original state, which defeats the whole purpose of randomizing it in the first place.

Comment: True, but perhaps it will be enough to throw off an emulator

Comment: Aha, security through obscurity... Not cryptography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An algorithm that loops through all permutations of a set with *n* items has a complexity of O(*n*!). Applying the algorithm to your example set with 9 items means 9! = 362880 iterations, which is probably feasible.

How is the encryption key derived from the 9-character string? Whoever designed this system didn't seem to have understood much about cryptography.

As for the permutation iteration algorithm, see e.g. this: [Stepping through all permutations one swap at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000048/stepping-through-all-permutations-one-swap-at-a-time)

Comment: The string was an example, would this still be feasible to a 256 bit AES key?

Comment: Hmm, would randomizing only the end 128 bits and applying permutation algorithm on it be sufficient then?

Comment: Is it too large because it is simply impossible to perform that operation or because it would take too long <10 minutes ?

Comment: If checking each permutation took 1 nanosecond, it would tak about 9e188 times the age of the universe to check them all. So it would take too long. Factorials increases extremely quickly.

Comment: 128! > 2^716, which implies that it would be much faster to brute force the 256-bit key (2^256 iterations).

Comment: Since you're not dealing with unique values but rather a permutation of bits the complexity shouldn't be 128! but 128!/((ones)! * (zeroes)!). Rather, you can just iterate through 2^128 and disqualify all results with the incorrect amount of bits set. This still takes forever, 2^128 is still very much.

Comment: 128!? Only if the OP wants to swap bit. If he is still swapping characters it would only be 16!. That is still an unrealistic number but much smaller then 128!

Comment: wrt. to enumerating/iterating ("bruteforcing") all permutations of a set in C++, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=std%3A%3Anext_permutation - this can be done on a C++ `std::string`, so `std::string cipher("hiiamacat"); while(test_cipher(cipher) && std::next_permutation(cipher.begin(), cipher.end());`

Answer (score 2):

If you can find out the string by brute force, then any one else can, and therefore there is no point in the encryption to begin with.